# Mvc Ienumerable in view for webgrid data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@model MedicalVariance.Models.ViewModels.IndividualProfile
    @Html.ListBox("AdministrationErrorSelected", Model.AdministrationErrorListBox, new { @class = "chzn-select" })
```

It look great and works just fine however! But I want to make an IEnumerable because I wanted to use a webgrid.

```
@model IEnumerable<MedicalVariance.Models.ViewModels.IndividualProfile>
@Html.ListBox("AdministrationErrorSelected", foreach(var model in Model)model.AdministrationErrorListBox, new { @class = "chzn-select" })


@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(source:Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,fieldNamePrefix:"details");
.... wouldnt work if the Model was not IEnumerable...
}
```

Any better ways? I dont like using foreach because it seems verbose.

Comment: What type is `AdministrationErrorListBox`? Now that your Model is collection, you have one `AdministrationErrorListBox` for each item. Which one would you like to show? All of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
@Html.ListBox("AdministrationErrorSelected", new SelectList(Model.Select(s => s.AdministrationErrorListBox)), new { @class = "chzn-select" });
```

Comment: This works however, i think I will create a .tolist method, create a property in my model and then use webgrid.